# Can't add right_action_items to KivyMD Toolbar

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to add 2 buttons to my MDToolbar, which would normally use the property right_action_items. My toolbar code looks like this:

```
        self.main_toolbar = MDToolbar(
        title = "Home",
        right_action_items = [["import", lambda args: print("import pressed")],["export", lambda args: print("export pressed")]],
        pos_hint = {"top": 1}
    )z

    self.smain.add_widget(self.main_toolbar)
```

self.smain is my screen variable.

The error I'm getting says there is a KeyError with "right_actions" somewhere in the kivymd module. There isn't any reference to my code in the error except it saying that the error was from my MDToolbar

Minimal reproduceable sample:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen()

        screen.add_widget(MDToolbar(
            title = "Placeholder",
            right_action_items = [["import", lambda x: print("import clicked")], ["export", lambda x: print("export clicked")]]
        ))

        return screen

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: What version of `kivy` are you using ?

Comment: I'm using kivymd, but ive got the most recent version installed

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ApuCoder, just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have a little thing to do with this problem (the problem is infact there in the source code of `MDToolbar` that works quite well in kvlang but not in python).

Here, you can use attr. `right_action_items` like a class attr. rather than a instance attr. as,

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen()

        self.tb = MDToolbar(
            title = "Placeholder",
        )
        self.tb.right_action_items = [["import", lambda x: print("import clicked")], ["export", lambda x: print("export clicked")]]
        screen.add_widget(self.tb)

        return screen

MyApp().run()
```